# react - generic notifications

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a generic notification service. I'm thinking of having a component which is attached to my app root component and listening for custom events. Then e.g. sending an event from different part of my app whenever I want to show a notification. I'm aware of using custom events is not the React way. This is my example

```
var Notification = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            notifications: []
        }
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
      window.addEventListener('notify', this.addNotification);
    },
    addNotification: function(data) {
        // TODO: Add notification, update state and rerender etc.
        console.log('event', data);
        var notifications = this.state.notifications;
        var notification = event.detail;

        notifications.push(notification);

        this.setState({ notifications: notifications });

        setTimeout(function() {
            notifications.splice(notifications.indexOf(notification), 1);
            this.setState({ notifications: notifications });
        }.bind(this), 2000);
    },
    render: function() {
        var notificationNodes = this.state.notifications.map(function(notification) {
            return (
                <div className="alert alert-warning " role="alert">
                    <strong>{notification.message}</strong> 
                </div>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {notificationNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Form = React.createClass({
    onSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var notificationEvent = new CustomEvent('notify', { 
            detail: { 
                message: 'this is new notification'
            },
            bubbles: true
        });

        window.dispatchEvent(notificationEvent);
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <input type='submit' value='Notify' />
            </form>
        );
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Notification />
                <Form />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<App/>, document.body);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pqLv47w0/41/

My question: is that a right way of doing it in react or there is a better one?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: updated code and question

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to introduce stores and actions in your app. One of the libs is called reflux https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs

You can find good docs on its github page.

Basically you will fire "notify" action from your Form component. Your Store will hold current notifications and listen to the "notify" action, and emit event when it changes. Notification component will listen to Store changes and update accordingly.